# add_role and set_role applying role to user

Tags: php, wordpress

In my plugin I call the following:

```
$caps = array("read"=>true, "edit_posts"=>false,"edit_other_posts"=>false,"edit_published_posts"=>false);
add_role("employee", "Employee", $caps);

add_role("manager", "Manager", $caps);
```

I'm trying to allow a dropdown for user account creation so an admin can choose whether or not the created user is a manager or an employee.

```
wp_create_user( $_POST['ae_uname'], $_POST['ae_pass'], $_POST['ae_email'] ); //new user registration
$user = get_userdatabylogin($_POST['ae_uname']); //get user information by username
$user_role = new WP_User( $user->ID );
$user_role->remove_role( 'subscriber' ); //remove user role
$user_role->remove_role( 'employee' ); //remove user role
//if ($_POST['employee_role'] == "manager") {
        $user_role->set_role( 'manager' ); //add new user
//} else { 
//   $user_role->add_role( 'employee' ); //add new user
//}
```

I verified all $_POST variables were submitting properly, but I went ahead and commented out the if statement just to be double sure.  If statement or no, every user that is created is assigned the role of 'employee'.

I've tried `$user_role->add_role( 'manager' );` and I tried `$user_role->set_role( 'manager' );`

Googling came up blank in terms of whether or not there was some 'default' role setting, and based off my `add_role()` code, I don't see how I could have specified "employee" as a default.

How can I make sure that WordPress honors my role setting?

Edit:

Additionally I've tried

```
  wp_update_user(
        array(
          'ID'       => $user->ID,
          'nickname' => $email_address,
          'role'    => 'manager'
        )
      );
```

Still no luck.  If I remove the "employee" role, the users are created with blank roles.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is enough for inserting a new users

```
 $userdata = array(
'user_login'  =>  $_POST['login_name'],
'user_url'    =>  'http://www.kvcodes.com',
'user_pass'   =>  NULL , // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
'role'      => 'employee');  

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ; 
// on success 
if(! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
      echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}
```

Before using the user entered data, just apply the stripslashes and trim to clean it . also use esc_attr to clean it .